# Pass a list to a get call Rest-Assured

Tags: list, get, rest-assured

I want to list the user's comment. I have gotten the list of post ids, I think of passing the ids of the post to the comments. I passed the id list to the comment url as below. When I did so it returned empty array -

```
[]
[
    
]
[]

post idList = [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
```

Pass list to a get command in RestAssured:

```
public static void searchForUserCommentinnPost( ) throws Throwable {
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = given();
        httpRequest.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Response response = httpRequest.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" +idList);

        // Get Response Body
        ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
        String bodyStringValue = body.asString();
        System.out.println(bodyStringValue);
        response.prettyPrint();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the list of query params like this:

```
@Test
void name() {
    List<Integer> postIds = Arrays.asList(81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90);
    Response res = RestAssured.given().queryParam("postId", postIds)
            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments");
    List<String> contents = res.jsonPath().getList("body");
    contents.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This is the result:

[image]